# how to save the $_post in the table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

im just askin how to create a form that will save the input in the $_post thingy into the table much appreciated thanks!! or can you help me fix this code or create a new one to work please? i need your help please thanks again!

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tsukishiro";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$input = $_POST['input'];


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO connection(ID, name, comment, input) VALUES ('null', '$name', '$comment', 'input')";



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

     if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }


   if (empty($_POST["input"])) {
     $input = "";
   } else {
     $input = test_input($_POST["input"]);
   }



function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

echo "<input type='text' name='id'>";<br><br>
echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='comment'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='input'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}



$conn->close();

?>`
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? What is the exact problem? Are you receiving any error?

Comment: You missed the form tag

Comment: You're using Joomla, so why not stick to the Joomla API. Have a read through the documentation

Comment: can you make a link for that please @lodder? please i need it badly :(( and also i just want to make a custom pre registration

Comment: Start here: http://docs.joomla.org . I won't provide each individual links ad I would personally re-write all your code and turn it into a small module

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<form>` tag.

```
<form name="form_name" action="your_page.php" method="post">
   <input type='text' name='id'>
   <input type='text' name='name'>
   <input type='text' name='comment'>
   <input type='text' name='input'>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Updated:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tsukishiro";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $input = $_POST['input'];

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

     if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }


   if (empty($_POST["input"])) {
     $input = "";
   } else {
     $input = test_input($_POST["input"]);
   }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO connection(ID, name, comment, input) VALUES ('null', '$name', '$comment', 'input')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}

$conn->close();

?>
<form name="form_name" action="" method="post">
   <input type='text' name='id'>
   <input type='text' name='name'>
   <input type='text' name='comment'>
   <input type='text' name='input'>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: but how to create that your_page.php ? sorry for asking :((

Comment: your_page.php is the page where your server side coding is? Here the same page itself.

Comment: im using joomla so where should i see the page.php? sorryyy again @arunrc

Comment: your_page.php means the page where your PHP code is done. In this case, the page which have the code you posted above. Just give the page name.

Comment: so this "http://localhost/joomla/index.php/admissions/pre-registration" or this index.php thing? :( sorry for the hard time explaining what should i do about this thing

Comment: ok. you just try `<form name='form_name' method='post' action=''>` for the time being and check whether all works fine.

Comment: theres no output in the page
`<form name='form_name' method='post' action=''> <inputtype='text'name='id'> <inputtype='text'name='name'> <inputtype='text'name='comment'> <inputtype='text'name='input'> <inputtype='submit'name='submit'></form>`

Comment: Do you get the form displayed?

Comment: nope im using joomla can you make some simple form with the source code in it? very much appreciated sir :( i dont know where to create .php with my joomla 3.3

Comment: I,m not familiar with Joomla.. Check my updated answer. Change your code like that and please check.

Comment: Still nothing appear?? Even the form??

Comment: oh..that's weird.. !! May be my problem with Joomla. Add Joomla tag to your question. You will get better opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You miss $ sign for input variable

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO connection(ID, name, comment, input) VALUES ('null', '$name', '$comment', '$input')";
```

Comment: where should i put the $sign?

Comment: check your $input variable in your insert query